# Stoping saved request that triggered the login, always redirect to `/`

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a web application that contains a REST api that is interacted with by the client application that lives at `/`. When a user session times out and the client js application makes a request to the REST api, that request will trigger a login event. Once the user logs in the user is then taken to the REST api endpoint which just displays a JSON response. I would like to hard wire the login page to always redirect to `/`.

Edit 1: I'm using spring-security-core plugin with the openid plugin as well and grails 2.0.4.

Edit 2: So I managed to get a solution working, however its a bit crude and I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution out there.

I created a simple filter in `grails-app/conf/LoginRedirectFilters.groovy`:

```
class RedirectLoginFilters {
    def filters = {
        redirectAfterLogin (uri: '/api/*') {
            before = {
                if (session["LOGGING_IN"])
                    redirect uri: "/"
            }
            after = {
                if (session["LOGGING_IN"])
                    session["LOGGING_IN"] = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `auth` function inside of `OpenIdController.groovy` I added the session flag `LOGGING_IN`:

```
def auth = {                                                                                     

    def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig                                              

    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {                                                    
        redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl                                     
        return                                                                                   
    }                                                                                            

    session["LOGGING_IN"] = true
    .
    .
    .
```

This is working properly by only checking if the `LOGGING_IN` flag is true when an api endpoint is called, and it also kills the flag after one request so it won't interfere with subsequent client api calls. I realize this is pretty convoluted, so if there is a better solution please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Are you using an AJAX request for the login?

Comment: No just the standard login, for now that is. Switching to an AJAX login system would undoubtedly fix the problem, however that is a back-burner feature right now.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the same "springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()" inside your filter as well? I'm pretty sure that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm misunderstanding exactly what you want to achieve, but if you always want to redirect to '/' after a successful login, just set these properties in your `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/"
```

If you want different behaviour to this, you'll have to flesh out your question.

Comment: Peter, I did get these set, but for some reason they do not get put into effect. I think its because I'm using the openid security plugin. I think I have found a work around which I will detail once I'm out of work.